How to connect backend and fronend in MVC
I am working on a  ERP project and I have models and also creating the frontend using Odoo-15 drag and drop feature bit I dont know how to link the backend with the fronend
For example I have a few fields in this model and I have defined them in a xml file as fields with tree and kanban views but I cant link them with the fronend page that I have created.
How can i link them with the front end part
from odoo import api, models, fields
from datetime import date

class CarListPage(models.Model):
    _name = "car.list.page"
    _inherit = 'mail.thread'
    _description = "Car Listing and Adding Page"
    
    car_brand = fields.Char(string="Car Brand", tracking=True)
    car_model = fields.Char(string="Car Model",tracking = True)
    car_year = fields.Date(string="Manufacturing Date", default=fields.Date.today())
    about_car = fields.Text(string="About Car", tracking=True)
    car_price_per_hour = fields.Float(string  = "Car Price", tracking = True)
    car_images = fields.Image(string = "Image", tracking = True)
    unique_id = fields.Char(string = "Unique ID", tracking = True)
    about_the_car = fields.Html(string = "Information About the Car", tracking = True)
    color_of_the_car = fields.Char(string = 'Color', tracking = True)
    damage_record = fields.Boolean(string = 'Damaged', tracking = True)
    damage_description = fields.Text(string='Damage Description')
    repair_cost = fields.Float(string='Repair Cost')
    car_age = fields.Integer(string="Car Age", compute='compute_age', store=False)
    color = fields.Integer(string='Color', default=0)  #kanban view side panel color picking 
    damage_record_details = fields.Char(string = "Damaged Records")

    ##Car Details

    car_type = fields.Selection([('sport','Sport'), ('suv', 'SUV'), ('sedan','Sedan'),('super_sport','Super-Sport'),('hybrid', 'Hybrid')])
    car_gas_detail = fields.Float(string = "Gas Per hour")
    car_gas_type = fields.Selection([('diesel', 'Diesel'),('gasoline','Gasoline')])
    
    
    


    def reload_page(self):
        
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.client',
            'tag': 'reload',
        }
    def action_test(self):
        print("Success")
        return{
            'effect':
            {
            'fadeout' : 'slow',
            'message' : 'Success',
            'type' : 'rainbow_man'
            }
       
        }
    
    
    @api.depends('car_year')
    def compute_age(self):
        today = date.today()
        for rec in self:
            if rec.car_year:
                manufactured = rec.car_year
                rec.car_age = today.year - manufactured.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (manufactured.month, manufactured.day))
            else:
                rec.car_age = 0


    def name_get(self):
        result = []
        for record in self:
            name = record.car_brand
            result.append((record.id, name))
        return result


I have tried controllers but looks like they just render pages
